# How to find Matches between two different sheet column and do vlookup to pull data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to partial vlookup type function in excel.
suppose we have two columns and if both the column have any single word match then revert back that cell with that matched cell value for another column in excel.
example

column A

```
arvind
Vimal
Yadav
```

Column B

```
Yeh Arvind
No Vimal dude
Yadav hai toh hai
```

Output

```
Column C     column D
arvind       Yeh Arvind
Vimal         No Vimal dude
Yadav        Yadav hai toh hai
```

Comment: A simple formula will set the values in `Column C` (i.e. put this in C1: `=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(LOWER($A1),LOWER($B1))), $A1, "")`). Not sure what the difference is between `Column B` and `Column D` though?

Comment: you could use `SEARCH` instead of `FIND` to make it case insensitive and omit `LOWER`.

Comment: @Zac,

Actually I have Column A value in sheet 1 and column B and I want to lookup those value in such way that if any of one word matches then sheet 2 column value goes the corresponding cell of sheet 1's column A. i.e, if sheet 1 column A have cell name "Arvind" and sheet 2 column B have "yeh arvind hai" then it will display in sheet 1 as
Column-A   Column-B
Arvind      yeh arvind hai

so in this situation, there are one match in both the sheets that is Arvind.

Comment: But your **Output** doesnt match what you just explained. Your output has column `C` and `D`? @OverflowStacker: you are absolutely correct